# Android process memory map

Tags: android, memory-management, linux-kernel, maps, dalvik

I try to understand the memory regions in the `com.android.browser` process [memory map below], and have a few questions:

1. For the address ranges without a pathname, what are mapped here?
2. There're multiple [stack:xxxx] regions, are they thread local
   stacks? If not, what are they? They seem to get mapped in many
   different locations scattered in the memory space.
3. If assuming the stack is at the top of the user space, then the
   user space memory is 2GB, the rest 2GB taken by the kernel space. Is
   it possible to see the memory map for the kernel space?
4. The `59eb5000-59fb5000 r-xp 00000000 00:04 3972
   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)` will be treated the
   same as code region?

```
    root@android:/ # cat /proc/2348/maps  
    Address           Perm Offset   Dev   Inode      Pathname
    22900000-22909000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    22909000-2290a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2290a000-229ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    229ff000-22a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2ae00000-2ae09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    2ae09000-2ae0a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2ae0a000-2ae4b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    2ae4b000-2ae4c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2e000000-2e300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2e300000-2e400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    2e400000-2e700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2e700000-2e800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    2ee00000-2ee09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    2ee09000-2ee0a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2ee0a000-2ee0b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    2ee0b000-2ee0c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    2f000000-2f100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    33c00000-33d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    35d00000-35d09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    35d09000-35d0a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    35d0a000-35dff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    35dff000-35e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    3a322000-3a422000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    3ab00000-3ab09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    3ab09000-3ab0a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    3ab0a000-3ab0b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    3ab0b000-3ab0c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    3fc00000-3fd00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    43c00000-43d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    4b200000-4b209000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    4b209000-4b20a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    4b20a000-4b20b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    4b20b000-4b20c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    4b800000-4b809000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    4b809000-4b80a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    4b80a000-4b80b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
    4b80b000-4b80c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    53486000-534a0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    534a0000-534b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    534b0000-534b6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    57709000-5773a000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4053       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/296-167/52682000/jpg/_52682670_jup6.jpg (deleted)
    5773a000-5776b000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4051       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/296-167/52688000/jpg/_52688304_facebookimage.jpg (deleted)
    5776b000-5779c000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4050       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/296-167/52680000/jpg/_52680897_kevin1_464afp.jpg (deleted)
    5779c000-5779d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5779d000-5789c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2405]
    5789c000-578db000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4041       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/spotlight-borg/336-189/spotlight_thequeen_120511.jpg (deleted)
    578ef000-57913000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4040       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/www.bbc.co.uk/img/sprite.png (deleted)
    57913000-5791f000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4039       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/144-81/52683000/jpg/_52683750_011954295-1.jpg (deleted)
    5791f000-57952000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4038       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/304-171/52689000/jpg/_52689400_011907423-1.jpg (deleted)
    57952000-579a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    57bf6000-57c63000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4054       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwtravel/img/ic/432-258/130322419618027417917_1.jpg (deleted)
    57c63000-57c6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4008       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/watches/B001A62M04._V192212155_.jpg (deleted)
    57c6f000-57c7b000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4007       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/watches/B0019FP47E._V192598089_.jpg (deleted)
    57c7b000-57c87000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4006       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/watches/B000EQR6H0._V192598437_.jpg (deleted)
    57c87000-57c94000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4004       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41cdbCsSRVL._SL135_.jpg (deleted)
    57c94000-57ca6000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4003       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51y8Ow-npiL._SL135_.jpg (deleted)
    57ca6000-57cc3000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4001       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/www.amazon.com/img/navPackedSprites-US-16piv._V172849515_.png (deleted)
    57cdb000-57ce8000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4037       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/296-167/52689000/gif/_52689818_c0078971-hiv_capsid_release.gif (deleted)
    57ce8000-57cff000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49769      /system/fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf
    57cff000-57d55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    57d55000-5827b000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49793      /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
    5827b000-582cc000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49783      /system/fonts/AndroidEmoji.ttf
    582cc000-582f7000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49787      /system/fonts/Lohit-Telugu.ttf
    582f7000-58328000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49775      /system/fonts/Lohit-Kannada.ttf
    58328000-5834b000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49768      /system/fonts/Lohit-Bengali.ttf
    5834b000-5834c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5834c000-5844b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2401]
    58456000-58462000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49796      /system/fonts/AnjaliNewLipi-light.ttf
    58462000-5846b000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49786      /system/fonts/DroidSansTamil-Bold.ttf
    5846b000-5848a000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49777      /system/fonts/DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf
    5848a000-58490000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49798      /system/fonts/DroidSansGeorgian.ttf
    58490000-58494000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49763      /system/fonts/DroidSansArmenian.ttf
    58494000-5849d000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49799      /system/fonts/DroidSansThai.ttf
    5849d000-584a5000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49779      /system/fonts/DroidSansHebrew-Bold.ttf
    584a5000-584dd000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49764      /system/fonts/DroidSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf
    584dd000-58504000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49791      /system/fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular-SystemUI.ttf
    58504000-5852d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5852d000-5859a000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4030       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwtravel/img/ic/432-258/130513460118259240140_1.jpg (deleted)
    5859a000-58608000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4029       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/432-259/52685000/jpg/_52685906_011803887-1.jpg (deleted)
    58608000-5864b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5864b000-58675000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4000       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kindle/merch/gw/v-day2011/vday-2011-gw-04-475x360._V170102477_.png (deleted)
    58675000-58676000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    58676000-58775000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2385]
    58775000-59245000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 3983       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/mich_engin.png (deleted)
    59245000-59515000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 3982       /dev/ashmem/gralloc-buffer (deleted)
    59515000-597e5000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 3974       /dev/ashmem/gralloc-buffer (deleted)
    597e5000-597e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    597e6000-59805000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2398]
    59805000-59806000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59806000-59825000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2397]
    59825000-59826000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59826000-59845000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2396]
    59845000-59846000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59846000-59865000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2395]
    59865000-59866000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59866000-59885000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2394]
    59885000-59886000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59886000-598a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2393]
    598a5000-598a6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    598a6000-598c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2392]
    598c5000-598c6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    598c6000-598e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2391]
    598e5000-598e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    598e6000-599e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2383]
    599e5000-59cb5000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 3971       /dev/ashmem/gralloc-buffer (deleted)
    59cb5000-59cb6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59cb6000-59db5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2378]
    59db5000-59db6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59db6000-59eb5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2377]
    59eb5000-59fb5000 r-xp 00000000 00:04 3972       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
    59fb5000-59fb6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    59fb6000-5a0b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2375]
    5a0b5000-5a0b6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a0b6000-5a1b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2373]
    5a1b5000-5a1b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a1b9000-5a1ba000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a1ba000-5a2b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2372]
    5a2b9000-5a2ba000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a2ba000-5a3b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2371]
    5a3bd000-5a3be000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a3be000-5a3dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2390]
    5a3dd000-5a3de000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a3de000-5a3fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2389]
    5a3fd000-5a3fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a3fe000-5a41d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2388]
    5a41e000-5a42a000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4049       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/bbc/static.bbc.co.uk/wwhomepage-3.5/ic/news/144-81/52685000/jpg/_52685275_52685269.jpg (deleted)
    5a42a000-5a42e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a430000-5a434000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a434000-5a438000 r--s 00478000 08:01 32786      /data/app/com.adobe.flashplayer-1.apk
    5a438000-5a454000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a455000-5a457000 r--s 0047b000 08:01 32786      /data/app/com.adobe.flashplayer-1.apk
    5a457000-5a469000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 4002       /dev/ashmem/file:///data/bbench/sites/amazon/ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/417XQ0XwQuL._SL135_.jpg (deleted)
    5a469000-5a46b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49468      /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
    5a46b000-5a46c000 r--p 00001000 08:01 49468      /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
    5a46c000-5a46d000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 49468      /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
    5a46d000-5a471000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a471000-5a472000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a472000-5a491000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2379]
    5a491000-5a499000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a499000-5a4ad000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49800      /system/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
    5a4ad000-5a4ae000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a4ae000-5a4bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2374]
    5a4bd000-5a4be000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a4be000-5a5bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2369]
    5a5bd000-5a5be000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a5be000-5a6bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2368]
    5a6bd000-5a6be000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a6be000-5a7bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2366]
    5a7bd000-5a7be000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a7be000-5a8bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2365]
    5a8bd000-5a8c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a8c1000-5a8c2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a8c2000-5a9c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2367]
    5a9c1000-5a9c2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5a9c2000-5aac1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2364]
    5aac1000-5aac5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5aac5000-5aac6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5aac6000-5abc5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2361]
    5abc5000-5abc9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5abc9000-5abfe000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 3952       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5abfe000-5ae8b000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17784      /data/dalvik-cache/system@app@Browser.apk@classes.dex
    5ae8b000-5ae91000 r--s 00295000 08:01 49237      /system/app/Browser.apk
    5ae91000-5aea2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    5aea2000-5afa3000 r--s 00191000 08:01 49237      /system/app/Browser.apk
    5afa3000-5afa9000 r--s 00295000 08:01 49237      /system/app/Browser.apk
    5afa9000-5afaa000 r--s 00000000 00:04 2842       /dev/ashmem/SurfaceFlinger read-only heap (deleted)
    5afaa000-5afae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5afae000-5afaf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5afaf000-5b0ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2360]
    5b0ae000-5b0b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b0b2000-5b0b3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b0b3000-5b1b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2359]
    5b1b2000-5b2b0000 r--p 00000000 00:0b 2566       /dev/binder
    5b2b0000-5b2b1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b2b1000-5b3b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2358]
    5b3b0000-5b3b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b3b4000-5b3b5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b3b5000-5b4b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2357]
    5b4b4000-5b4b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b4b8000-5b4b9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b4b9000-5b5b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2356]
    5b5b8000-5b5c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b5c0000-5b5c1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5b5c1000-5b6c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2355]
    5b6c0000-5be95000 r--s 00000000 08:01 50052      /system/usr/icu/icudt48l.dat
    5be95000-5bf0c000 r--s 00000000 08:01 50060      /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.dat
    5bf0c000-5c5b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49555      /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    5c5b3000-5c5b4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5c5b4000-5c62c000 r--p 006a7000 08:01 49555      /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    5c62c000-5c638000 rw-p 0071f000 08:01 49555      /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    5c638000-5c660000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5c660000-5c76f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49529      /system/lib/libbcinfo.so
    5c76f000-5c770000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5c770000-5c774000 r--p 0010f000 08:01 49529      /system/lib/libbcinfo.so
    5c774000-5c775000 rw-p 00113000 08:01 49529      /system/lib/libbcinfo.so
    5c775000-5cbda000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49549      /system/lib/libbcc.so
    5cbda000-5cc03000 r--p 00464000 08:01 49549      /system/lib/libbcc.so
    5cc03000-5cc05000 rw-p 0048d000 08:01 49549      /system/lib/libbcc.so
    5cc05000-5cc28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5cc28000-5cca9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49554      /system/lib/libRS.so
    5cca9000-5ccaa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5ccaa000-5ccac000 r--p 00081000 08:01 49554      /system/lib/libRS.so
    5ccac000-5ccad000 rw-p 00083000 08:01 49554      /system/lib/libRS.so
    5ccad000-5ccb3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49573      /system/lib/librs_jni.so
    5ccb3000-5ccb4000 r--p 00005000 08:01 49573      /system/lib/librs_jni.so
    5ccb4000-5ccb5000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 49573      /system/lib/librs_jni.so
    5ccb6000-5ccc3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49522      /system/lib/libandroid.so
    5ccc3000-5ccc5000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 49522      /system/lib/libandroid.so
    5ccc5000-5ccc6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5ccc6000-5ccd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49423      /system/lib/libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
    5ccd2000-5ccd3000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 49423      /system/lib/libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
    5ccd3000-5ccd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5ccd4000-5cce5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49425      /system/lib/libmtp.so
    5cce5000-5cce7000 r--p 00010000 08:01 49425      /system/lib/libmtp.so
    5cce7000-5cce8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5cce8000-5ce7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49422      /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    5ce7d000-5ce8a000 r--p 00194000 08:01 49422      /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    5ce8a000-5ce8b000 rw-p 001a1000 08:01 49422      /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    5ce8b000-5ce9d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5ce9d000-5ceb5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49589      /system/lib/libvorbisidec.so
    5ceb5000-5ceb6000 r--p 00017000 08:01 49589      /system/lib/libvorbisidec.so
    5ceb6000-5ceb7000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 49589      /system/lib/libvorbisidec.so
    5ceb7000-5cec9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49491      /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so
    5cec9000-5cecb000 r--p 00011000 08:01 49491      /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so
    5cecb000-5cecc000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 49491      /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so
    5cecc000-5cee0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49534      /system/lib/libdrmframework.so
    5cee0000-5cee3000 r--p 00013000 08:01 49534      /system/lib/libdrmframework.so
    5cee3000-5cee4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5cee4000-5cfc4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49484      /system/lib/libstagefright.so
    5cfc4000-5cfc5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5cfc5000-5cfcb000 r--p 000e0000 08:01 49484      /system/lib/libstagefright.so
    5cfcb000-5cfcc000 rw-p 000e6000 08:01 49484      /system/lib/libstagefright.so
    5cfcc000-5cff4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49512      /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
    5cff4000-5cff5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5cff5000-5cff6000 r--p 00028000 08:01 49512      /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
    5cff6000-5cff7000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 49512      /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
    5cff7000-5d00b000 r--s 00000000 08:01 49789      /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
    5d00b000-5d03b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d03b000-5d50f000 r--s 00336000 08:01 49813      /system/framework/framework-res.apk
    5d50f000-5d53f000 r--s 00829000 08:01 49813      /system/framework/framework-res.apk
    5d540000-5d548000 rw-s 00000000 08:01 50110      /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/browser2.db-shm
    5d548000-5d550000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d550000-5d551000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d551000-5d650000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2354]
    5d650000-5d654000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d654000-5d655000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d655000-5d754000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2353]
    5d754000-5d758000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d758000-5d759000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5d759000-5d858000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2351]
    5d858000-5e02d000 r--s 00000000 08:01 50052      /system/usr/icu/icudt48l.dat
    5e02d000-5e061000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49502      /system/lib/libjavacore.so
    5e061000-5e062000 r--p 00033000 08:01 49502      /system/lib/libjavacore.so
    5e062000-5e064000 rw-p 00034000 08:01 49502      /system/lib/libjavacore.so
    5e064000-5e07c000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2802       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5e07c000-5e1cd000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17699      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@apache-xml.jar@classes.dex
    5e1cd000-5e1cf000 r--s 00085000 08:01 49807      /system/framework/apache-xml.jar
    5e1d0000-5e1d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e1d4000-5e1dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49417      /system/lib/libexif.so
    5e1dc000-5e1dd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e1dd000-5e1de000 r--p 00008000 08:01 49417      /system/lib/libexif.so
    5e1de000-5e1df000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 49417      /system/lib/libexif.so
    5e1df000-5e1e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e1e0000-5e206000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2801       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5e206000-5e42e000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17698      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@services.jar@classes.dex
    5e42e000-5e47c000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17697      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@android.policy.jar@classes.dex
    5e47c000-5e47d000 r--s 0001f000 08:01 49810      /system/framework/android.policy.jar
    5e47e000-5e483000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e483000-5e484000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e484000-5e489000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49504      /system/lib/libstagefright_avc_common.so
    5e489000-5e48a000 r--p 00004000 08:01 49504      /system/lib/libstagefright_avc_common.so
    5e48a000-5e48b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e48b000-5e48c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49566      /system/lib/libstagefright_enc_common.so
    5e48c000-5e48d000 r--p 00000000 08:01 49566      /system/lib/libstagefright_enc_common.so
    5e48d000-5e48e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5e48e000-5e55e000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2797       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5e55e000-5f033000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17696      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
    5f033000-5f04f000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2796       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5f04f000-5f1be000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17695      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@ext.jar@classes.dex
    5f1be000-5f1d0000 r--s 000f7000 08:01 49815      /system/framework/ext.jar
    5f1d0000-5f2c0000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17694      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@bouncycastle.jar@classes.dex
    5f2c0000-5f2c1000 r--s 00057000 08:01 49814      /system/framework/bouncycastle.jar
    5f2c1000-5f2c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49476      /system/lib/libstagefright_yuv.so
    5f2c3000-5f2c4000 r--p 00001000 08:01 49476      /system/lib/libstagefright_yuv.so
    5f2c4000-5f2c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5f2c5000-5f2c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    5f2c9000-5f2ca000 r--s 000e3000 08:01 49820      /system/framework/services.jar
    5f2ca000-5f2d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2800       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5f2d2000-5f2d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2794       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5f2d3000-5f2da000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17693      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core-junit.jar@classes.dex
    5f2da000-5f2db000 r--s 00002000 08:01 49826      /system/framework/core-junit.jar
    5f2db000-5f314000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2790       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5f314000-5f652000 r--p 00000000 08:01 17692      /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
    5f652000-5f653000 r--s 0013a000 08:01 49819      /system/framework/core.jar
    5f653000-5f654000 r--s 0041b000 08:01 49825      /system/framework/framework.jar
    5f654000-5f664000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2795       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
    5f664000-5f665000 ---p 00000000 00:04 2786       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    5f665000-5f90a000 rw-p 00001000 00:04 2786       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    5f90a000-5f94e000 rw-p 002a6000 00:04 2786       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    5f94e000-60664000 ---p 002ea000 00:04 2786       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    60664000-6066a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    6066a000-6086b000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2785       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-card-table (deleted)
    6086b000-65dc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2784       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
    65dc1000-661c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2783       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-bitmap-2 (deleted)
    661c1000-665c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2782       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-bitmap-1 (deleted)
    665c1000-66be3000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 2781       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    66be3000-66d43000 rw-p 00622000 00:04 2781       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    66d43000-765c1000 ---p 00782000 00:04 2781       /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    765c1000-765c2000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
    765c2000-765ca000 r--s 00000000 00:0b 1945       /dev/__properties__ (deleted)
    765ca000-765fd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49574      /system/lib/libharfbuzz.so
    765fd000-765fe000 r--p 00032000 08:01 49574      /system/lib/libharfbuzz.so
    765fe000-765ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    765ff000-76601000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49432      /system/lib/libusbhost.so
    76601000-76602000 r--p 00001000 08:01 49432      /system/lib/libusbhost.so
    76602000-76603000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76603000-76604000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49436      /system/lib/libmedia_native.so
    76604000-76605000 r--p 00000000 08:01 49436      /system/lib/libmedia_native.so
    76605000-76606000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76606000-76609000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49521      /system/lib/libspeexresampler.so
    76609000-7660a000 r--p 00002000 08:01 49521      /system/lib/libspeexresampler.so
    7660a000-7660b000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 49521      /system/lib/libspeexresampler.so
    7660b000-7660d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49580      /system/lib/libaudioutils.so
    7660d000-7660e000 r--p 00001000 08:01 49580      /system/lib/libaudioutils.so
    7660e000-7660f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    7660f000-76619000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49452      /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
    76619000-7661a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    7661a000-7661b000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 49452      /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
    7661b000-7661c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 49452      /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
    7661c000-7667a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49490      /system/lib/libmedia.so
    7667a000-7667b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    7667b000-7668b000 r--p 0005e000 08:01 49490      /system/lib/libmedia.so
    7668b000-7668c000 rw-p 0006e000 08:01 49490      /system/lib/libmedia.so
    7668c000-766be000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49513      /system/lib/libssl.so
    766be000-766bf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    766bf000-766c1000 r--p 00032000 08:01 49513      /system/lib/libssl.so
    766c1000-766c4000 rw-p 00034000 08:01 49513      /system/lib/libssl.so
    766c4000-76788000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49487      /system/lib/libcrypto.so
    76788000-76789000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    76789000-76795000 r--p 000c4000 08:01 49487      /system/lib/libcrypto.so
    76795000-7679b000 rw-p 000d0000 08:01 49487      /system/lib/libcrypto.so
    ...
    76ed1000-76ed2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76ed2000-76eea000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49418      /system/lib/libutils.so
    76eea000-76eeb000 r--p 00017000 08:01 49418      /system/lib/libutils.so
    76eeb000-76eec000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 49418      /system/lib/libutils.so
    76eec000-76efb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49462      /system/lib/libcutils.so
    76efb000-76efc000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 49462      /system/lib/libcutils.so
    76efc000-76efd000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 49462      /system/lib/libcutils.so
    76efd000-76f0b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76f0b000-76f20000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49424      /system/lib/libm.so
    76f20000-76f21000 r--p 00014000 08:01 49424      /system/lib/libm.so
    76f21000-76f22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76f22000-76f23000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49474      /system/lib/libstdc++.so
    76f23000-76f24000 r--p 00000000 08:01 49474      /system/lib/libstdc++.so
    76f24000-76f25000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76f25000-76f68000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49489      /system/lib/libc.so
    76f68000-76f6b000 rw-p 00043000 08:01 49489      /system/lib/libc.so
    76f6b000-76f76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76f76000-76f79000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49505      /system/lib/liblog.so
    76f79000-76f7a000 r--p 00002000 08:01 49505      /system/lib/liblog.so
    76f7a000-76f7b000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 49505      /system/lib/liblog.so
    76f7b000-76f8e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49277      /system/bin/linker
    76f8e000-76f8f000 r--p 00012000 08:01 49277      /system/bin/linker
    76f8f000-76f90000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 49277      /system/bin/linker
    76f90000-76f9c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    76f9c000-76f9e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 49334      /system/bin/app_process
    76f9e000-76f9f000 r--p 00001000 08:01 49334      /system/bin/app_process
    76f9f000-76fa0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    772af000-773f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    773f8000-77bf0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    7ec4f000-7ec70000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
    ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) The unnamed regions could be anything.  As one example, the dlmalloc implementation will use mmap() to allocate large regions (where "large" is configurable; might be 64K or 256K).

(2) The [stack:xxxx] stacks are thread stacks for the specified thread; each is 1MB with a guard page to trap over/underruns.  They won't all be sequential because not all threads are started at the same time.

(3) The kernel starts at 0xc0000000.  ASLR causes things to be placed somewhat randomly.  There are various tools for poking at the Linux kernel.

(4) The dalvik-jit-code-cache is executable code.  Note the 'x' (execute) flag is set.

Comment: Thanks fadden! Can you mention a few tools for poking at the Linux kernel? I've found the following for ARM Linux which seems to match with the [vectors] section.http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/memory.txt

Comment: For the memory map shown, the 'norandmaps' boot option was turned on to prevent ASLR.